# Postgres aggregate row to string

Tags: postgresql

If I have a following query:

```
SELECT 'a' AS a, 1 AS b, CURRENT_DATE AS c;
```

It's possible to aggregate row to string as:

```
SELECT concat_ws(', ', a, b, c) FROM (
    SELECT 'a' AS a, 1 AS b, CURRENT_DATE AS c
) AS T;

-- Result: "a, 1, <CURRENT DATE>"
```

But what I can't seem to find - if there is already existing function in postgres (version 9.3 or 9.4) that will produce the same result as above, but operating with a "*"

```
--
-- Something like:
--
-- some_function(<separator>,  *) - ???
--
SELECT some_function(', ', *) FROM (
    SELECT 'a' AS a, 1 AS b, CURRENT_DATE AS c
) AS T;

-- so the result would be - "a, 1, <CURRENT DATE>"
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hmm. Don't understand the question... "something like t" threw me off

Comment: No there isn't. Best you can do is a function to read all fields from the table and create the concatenated list of fields then you use this list to create and run your sql statement dinamically

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convert the row to a [`hstore`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/hstore.html), you can do that:

```
select array_to_string(avals(hstore(x)), ', ')
from (
  SELECT 'a' AS a, 1 AS b, CURRENT_DATE AS c
) x
```

`hstore(x)` will convert all column values to strings and then put them into the hstore. `avals` then extracts the values as a string array, and `array_to_string` converts it into a comma separated list.

To do that for a regular table, you need to pass the table name, not `*`

```
select array_to_string(avals(hstore(foobar)), ', ')
from foobar;
```

If you don't want to (or can't) install the `hstore` extension, you can do this with the JSON function although it requires one more level of nesting:

```
select string_agg(value, ', ') 
from (
  select (json_each_text(row_to_json(x1))).value
  from (
    SELECT 'a' AS a, 1 AS b, CURRENT_DATE AS c
  ) x1
) x2
```

Or to get the data from a table:

```
select string_agg(value, ', ') 
from (
  select (json_each_text(row_to_json(foobar))).value
  from foobar
) x
```

If you want you can "hide" this in a function:

```
create or replace function concat_record(p_data anyelement, p_delim text)
  returns text
as $$
   select array_to_string(avals(hstore(p_data)), p_delim);
$$
language sql;
```

And then you can do:

```
select concat_record(foobar, ', ')
from foobar;
```

---

Unrelated but: you don't need the `select` for the dummy data:

```
select *
from (
  values ('a', 1, CURRENT_DATE)
) as x (a,b,c);
```

Is a bit shorter to write - especially if you have more than one row.

```
select *
from (
  values 
     ('a', 1, CURRENT_DATE), 
     ('x', 2, date  '2015-07-01')
) as x (a,b,c);
```

Comment: Thanks, it kind of works and it doesn't. It will produce the desired result, but there is a slightly different meaning for parameters (I think I should update a question with better example). "\*" would mean all columns (maybe from multiple table). and I don't think it's possible to do hstore(\*), or row_to_json(\*).

Comment: @DmitryF No, you need to pass the identifier for the _row_, not `*`. The `x` has to be the name of the table (or the alias) you are selecting from. It represents all columns for a single row.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking that too, though I guess concat_ws(', ', array_to_string(avals(hstore(T1)), ', '), array_to_string(avals(hstore(T2)), ', ')) - might not be that bad ( and probably can't be improve, it's just a rough version )